# Write a sql to retrieve names of all students with S grade in all the courses he/she has attempted?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been practicing DBMS queries and I'm stuck with the following sql query:

Write a sql to retrieve names of all students with S grade in all the courses he/she has attempted?

Following are my tables and code

```
create table COURSE
(
  cId int primary key,
  cName varchar(30),
  credits int not null
);

create table student
(
   usn int primary key,
   sname varchar(20),
   dno int
);

create table RESULT
(
  SUsn int,
  CCode int,
  Grade char,
  primary key(SUsn,CCode)
);
```

Code:

```
select S.sname 
from student S inner join result R on S.usn = R.susn
where grade = 'S'
group by S.usn,S.sname
having count(*) in (
                     select count(*) from result
                     group by susn
                   );
```

May I know where I'm going wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually overcomplicating the question.  You are answering the question about students who have gotten an "S" in all courses.  For this question, you only need to see if any grades are not "S":

```
select S.sname 
from student S inner join
     result R
     on S.usn = R.susn
group by S.usn, S.sname
having sum(case when grade <> 'S' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: If grade is nullable (it is not declared not null), a check for null would need to be added.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there any other way to write this sql as im not fimilar with case usage?

Comment: You can but will complicate things. Take this opportunity to learn something new. Check the [**CASE**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT usn,
       sname
FROM ( SELECT usn AS usn,
              sName AS sName,
              SUM( CASE
                       WHEN Grade = 'S' THEN
                           1
                       ELSE
                           0
                   END ) AS sCount,
              COUNT( * ) AS totalCount
       INNER JOIN result on student.usn = result.SUsn
       FROM student
       GROUP BY usn
     ) AS usnCounter
WHERE usnCounter.sCount = usnCounter.totalCount
ORDER BY sname;
```

This statement starts by selecting each `usn` and `sname` from `student` along with a count of `courses` that a `student` has undertaken where their `Grade` equals `S`, and a count of all `courses` that a `student` has undertaken, irrespective of their `Grade`.

The `usn` and `sname` is then chosen from the list so generated `WHERE` the count of `Grade` values for a student that equal `S` equal the total count of `courses` for that student.

I have included `usn` in the results so as to uniquely identify `students` as it can not be safely assumed that no two students will have the same value for `sname`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.